# In NDSolve, how to involve in the odes a integration function that depends on ode functions and can't be analytically integrated?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I think it would be better to use this simple code to explain my questions:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Sin[y1[t] y2[t] r]/r, {r, a, b}];

  (* int[a_, b_] := NIntegrate[Sin[y1[t] y2[t] r]/r, {r, a, b}];*) 
  (* This works, but gives some warnings. *)


odes = {y1'[t] == y2[t] y3[t], 
   y2'[t] == -y1[t] y3[t] + int[y2[t], y3[t]], 
   y3'[t] == -0.51 y1[t] y2[t] t, y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1, y3[0] == 2};


sol = NDSolve[odes, {y1, y2, y3}, {t, 0, 12}];
Plot[{y1[t], y2[t], y3[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 12}]
```

The above code doesn't work, and gives the `"NIntegrate::inumr:` errors:
 "The integrand Sin[r\y1[t]\y2[t]]/r has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.,2.}}."

Two question:

(1) I want all the functions in my odes are purely numerically defined (i.e., use `_?Numeric@`), why mathematica doesn't allow this. mathematica seems treat all ode functions (y1,y2,y3 in my code) analytically, so is it possible to use a numerically defined function (`int` in my code) that depend on ode functions in NDSolve?

(2) If I delete `_?Numeric@` (which is not my favored solution), the code posted works, but gives warnings, how can I avoid these warnings.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Look at the error message again. The variables `a` and `b` do receive numerical values, but `y1` and `y2` do not...

Comment: @sebhofer Thanks for the quick response. Then how can I defined a tntegration function that depends on ode functions (i.e., how to define `int` in my above code) ?

Comment: Replacing `NIntegrate` with `Integrate` fixed that specific problem. But then you use symbolic again. I don't think this can be done completely numerical.

Comment: @Feyre, thanks. Actually, this problem originated from a mathematica versions of a  Matlab code in my research. The odes in my research is much more complicated than the code posted here, and it involves a integration term that (a) can't be analytically integrated and (b) depends on ode functions. So you means such odes can't be handled by `NDSolve`?

Comment: make all dependencys explicit arguments. in this example the whole product y1 y2 can be passed as a single argument

Comment: @Feyre Sure it can... Guo, you could use `int[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ,y1_?NumericQ,y2_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[Sin[y1 y2 r]/r, {r, a, b}]` (or something more streamlined), calling it with `int[y2[t],y3[t],y1[t],y2[t]]`. This yields the same plot as in the answer by rewi below.

Comment: @Feyre, thanks! :) The solution in your comments solved my problem perfectly.But how can I choose it as the best answer?

Comment: Per your comment, I made mine into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[a_, b_] = Integrate[Sin[y1[t] y2[t] r]/r, {r, a, b}, Assumptions -> a < b]
odes = {y1'[t] == y2[t] y3[t], 
  y2'[t] == -y1[t] y3[t] + int[y2[t], y3[t]], 
  y3'[t] == -0.51 y1[t] y2[t] t, y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1, y3[0] == 2}

sol = NDSolve[odes, {y1, y2, y3}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

to answer your question in your comment:

```
int[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[y1 y2 + Cos[r]]/(Cos[r] + 2), {r, a, b}]
odes := {
  y1'[t] == y2[t] y3[t],
  y2'[t] == -y1[t] y3[t] + int[y2[t], y3[t], y1[t], y2[t]],
  y3'[t] == -0.51 y1[t] y2[t] t,
  y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1, y3[0] == 2}

sol = NDSolve[odes, {y1, y2, y3}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: no need for a delayed set ...

Comment: @george2079  you are right, I edit it; thanks.

Comment: @rewi thanks, but this not what I want, because if you meet a more complicated integrand, `Integrate` would run "forever", so your code would fail (I have tested this by changing the integrand). `NIntegrate` is a must for me.

Comment: @rewi, for example, if the integrand in my code is `Sin[y1[t] y2[t] + Cos[r]]/(Cos[r] + 2)`, then your code would fail.

Comment: @Guo Xinxin it's all right!